# Подключить валидацию на стороне клиента yii2 в поле через activeTextInput

Tags: yii2, валидация, формы

```
Html::activeTextInput($form, 'email', [ 'placeholder' => "",'class' => 'form-control'])
```

Подскажите, как подключить email валидацию на стороне клиента yii2. Поле именно через activeTextInput нужно делать или каким-либо иным способом, чтобы yii2 не тянул свой jquery... 
p.s У модели настроен [['email'], 'email']
ап: на сайте подключен свой  jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: Jquery вообще не используется на сайте?

Comment: используется, но свой: jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: Дак отключите просто подключение юишного jquery и делайте вывод формы обычным способом со встроенной валидацией. Добавьте просто в конфиг в разделе `components` - `'assetManager' => ['bundles' => ['yii\web\JqueryAsset' => ['js' => []]]`

Comment: юишные ассеты в appasset - отключены

Comment: Зачем? Только из-за jquery?